# Upgrading from HDD to SSD, how to reinstall Microsoft Office 2016 Volume Licensing?

Tags: microsoft-office, volume-license

I just received a notebook from my company, it comes preinstalled with Windows 7 and Microsoft Office 2016 Professional.

The notebook is using HDD, which is slow and I hate it. I am accustomed to fast SSD therefore I decided to swap the HDD with an SSD of mine, reinstall Windows 7 and Microsoft Office.

Before swapping the drive I retrieved the product key for the Windows 7 and the Microsoft Office using this tool: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html

Windows installs and reactivated fine... but Microsoft Office refuses to accept the activation key saying the key is for Volume Licensing something and urged me to contact the administrator.

Obviously I do not want to go through the hassle of informing my company (and the red tapes it involves) of explaining that I dislike their HDD and I just removed their HDD, reinstalled the OS and Office etc.. etc..

So is there a way to reactivate this Office? Or am I at dead end here and have to live with HDD?

**EDIT**

I cloned the drive using a backup software..., it seems to work but then today I am seeing this message... probably because I upgraded to Windows 10?

[image]

Comment: Clone the old drive to the new SSD.

Comment: @Moab, know any good cloning software? I tried with 2 free cloning software but after cloning Windows does not boot... missing boot partition or something... or maybe I didn't try hard enough... will retry later if this is the only option.

Comment: https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree

Comment: @Moab, Well it works!... and it is easier than I anticipated! Thanks to the excellent Macrium Reflect! The procedure is quite simple, image my HDD, then restore it to my SDD... the whole process is quite intuitive. I now have a fast notebook and Ms Office installed! yay! Feel free to add that as answer if you want and I will accept it.

Comment: @Moab, Ops!... speak too soon... today I am seeing 'Activation Required' message in About page.. (see updated question)... :-(